# Grep from multiple files, modify contents of matching lines in vim interactively , after save, changes should be saved to corresponding files

Tags: vim, sed, grep

Every once a while. I need to do massive changes across multiple files in a project. Normally I'll do something like this:

> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/patten/replace/g"

But the above process is not intuitive. What if there's one line in a file that I don't want to change? It's too late, because I can't see the final change before it's actually done.

What I want is that I can first grep in project. All matching lines are listed in a buffer, I can edit these lines in my text editor, after I have finished modification. When I save the file, changes should be saved to corresponding files.

With this procedure, I can see the final results before the changes are made.  And I don't need to substitute all occurrences of a matching string with one replace string. Instead I can change some of them to one value and the others to another value.

I'm not sure if there's any unix utility which can achieve this?

Comment: `:h grepprg`, `:h cdo`, `:h ldo`

Comment: There is [a vim plugin](https://github.com/Olical/vim-enmasse) that does this, provided you somehow filled your quickfix window with the locations (e.g. using `:grep`):

Comment: @L3viathan, thanks for this excellent plugin. I think it solves my problem perfectly.